# How To Reduce Queries On Layout .NET Core

Tags: database, caching, razor, layout, .net-core

I created a class for getting my settings of website. In this settings table I'm storing phone number, email adress, address etc. Admin user can change their settings.

```
public interface IAppGlobalVariableService
{
    Task<List<Configuration>> GetAllConfig();
    Task<string> GetValue(string name);
}

public class AppGlobalVariablesService : IAppGlobalVariableService
{
    private readonly IRepository<Configuration> _configRepository;
    private static Task<List<Configuration>> _configList;

    public AppGlobalVariablesService(IRepository<Configuration> configRepository)
    {
        _configRepository = configRepository;
        _configList = GetAllConfig();
    }

    public async Task<List<Configuration>> GetAllConfig()
    {
        return await _configRepository.GetAll().ToListAsync();
    }

    public Task<string> GetValue(string name)
    {
        return GetConfigByName(name);
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetConfigByName(string name)
    {
        var configList = await _configList;
        return configList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConfigName == name)?.ConfigValue;
    }
}
```

In layout, I'm calling my settings like view components style.

```
@await AppConfig.GetValue("Facebook")
```

I injected _ViewImports

```
@inject IAppGlobalVariableService AppConfig
```

I will use this code most of place. Do you have any idea to reduce queries for dotnet core 2.2 ? Can I do something like querying database once to get variables. And store cache ?

**UPDATE:** 
I updated my startup.cs file (AddTransient to AddScoped) It redureced queries. But I want to learn can I use single query ?

```
services.AddScoped<IAppGlobalVariableService, AppGlobalVariablesService>();
```

Comment: Instead of using `AddScoped`, use `AddSingleton`.

Comment: I used but i recieved an error. "Cannot Consume Scoped Service From Singleton"

Comment: What about `IRepository`? If it is `scoped` or `transient`,  the error you've got is because of that. A `Singleton` cannot reference a `Scoped` instance.